# DynamoDBLocal error: package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.embedded does not exist

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-local

I am creating local app to create **DynamoDBLocal** and test against it.

I am using **Spring Boot** app with **gradle** on **Mac OS X**

However, while compiling, I get following error:

> **error: package com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.embedded does not exist**

I have following code:

`testCompile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'DynamoDBLocal', version: '1.11.119'`

```
task copyNativeDeps(type: Copy) {
    from(configurations.compile + configurations.testCompile) {
        include '*.dll'
        include '*.dylib'
        include '*.so'
    }
    into 'build/libs'
}

test {
    dependsOn copyNativeDeps
    systemProperty "java.library.path", 'build/libs'
}
```

```java
@Bean
public AmazonDynamoDB builAmazonDynamoDBClient() {
   return DynamoDBEmbedded.create().amazonDynamoDB();
}
```

Can someone please help me in understanding that why this is not being loaded ?

I can see the dependency being downloaded in my `.gradle⁩ ▸ ⁨caches⁩ ▸ ⁨modules-2⁩ ▸ ⁨files-2.1⁩ ▸ ⁨com.amazonaws⁩`

And I can see all the classes in it too.

However, in **eclipse**, all the classes have `Source Not Found` and terminal **./gradlew clean build** fails with above error.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would help now. I also faced a similar issue, and you would need to use compile instead of testCompile, if creating the Bean or calling **DynamoDBEmbedded.create()** outside of Test files.

```
compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'DynamoDBLocal', version: '1.11.119'
```